# Was there any preparation for the first coming of Christ taking place in the spiritual world during OT time?

Tags: old-testament, spiritual-warfare

Does the Bible contain a thought or any indication of it that throughout the whole Old Testament era there was a process of preparation for the first coming of Christ taking place in the spiritual world?

We know that in the physical world there was a process of preparation taking place for the first coming of Christ – in the way of God’s firstly forming a chosen nation, then revealing to them some standards of His righteousness, and later, through multiple periods of their history, showing to them that they were unable to live according to those standards by themselves, that they needed to fully rely on God’s saving hand in the matter of their salvation – despite possessing the status of  the chosen nation.

But what about the spiritual world? Does the Bible contain any indication that there was also a kind of preparation for the first coming of Christ happening in the spiritual world during those times (perhaps, some kind of spiritual warfare happening between God’s angels and fallen angels, the outcome of which made the first coming of Christ possible)?

Comment: The revelation of such a concept is not given until John's visions. _And his tail drew the third part of the stars of heaven, and did cast them to the earth: **and the dragon stood before the woman which was ready to be delivered, for to devour her child as soon as it was born**._ Revelation 12:4.

Comment: @Nigel - Isn't that about the second coming already?

Comment: The child _as soon as it was born_.

Comment: @NigelJ - It all depends on how you interpret the child. I heard the interpretation according to which the woman is the church and the child is the faithful saints produced by the church - those who will be raptured before the second coming of Christ.

Answer (score 1):

Most scholars who study apocalypsism would place the timing of the development of the idea of a meshiach delivering Israel and bringing an end to the current world and ushering in a kingdom where God appoints a righteous ruler over the nations happened between Malachi and the writing of Daniel during the Maccabean dynasty. Daniel and Ezekiel were among the first to write of such a thing. The fuller development happened in a book quoted by New Testament authors, but was rejected by the canonization process of the early orthodox church -- the Book of Enoch. I would suggest looking up some podcasts by Michael Heiser or the website Naked Bible to get a deeper understanding of this view. While the Old Testament/Hebrew Bible does contains the seeds for the apocalytic views, they remain very undeveloped. For example, it speaks of a descendant of David on the throne, but does not clearly speak of the overthrow of the then current world system and ushering in another system. Hints are given, such as swords to plowshares and the sheep lying beside the lion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Bible contain any indication that there was also a kind of preparation for the first coming of Christ happening in the spiritual world during those times?

Yes, but perhaps not in the way the the OP suggests: "some kind of spiritual warfare happening between God’s angels and fallen angels, the outcome of which made the first coming of Christ possible."

That the spiritual world was aware of the coming of the Messiah (Christ) is dramatically evidenced in the call of Isaiah, which takes place at God's throne in the spiritual realm.

> Then one of the seraphs flew to me, holding a live coal that had been
> taken from the altar with a pair of tongs. 7 The seraph touched my
> mouth with it and said, “Now that this has touched your lips, your
> guilt has departed and your sin is blotted out.” 8 Then I heard the
> voice of the Lord saying, “Whom shall I send, and who will go for us?”
> And I said, “Here am I; send me!”...
>
> 11 Then I said, “How long, O Lord?” And he said, “Until cities lie
> waste
> without inhabitant, and houses without people,
> and the land is utterly desolate; 12 until the Lord sends everyone far away,
> and vast is the emptiness in the midst of the land. 13 Even if a tenth part remain in it,
> it will be burned again, like a terebinth or an oak
> whose stump remains standing
> when it is felled.” **The holy seed is its stump.**

Out of this seed and stump arises the famous "branch," another symbol of the Messiah mentioned by Isaiah and others several times:

> A shoot shall come out from the stump of Jesse,
> and a branch shall grow out of his roots. 2 The spirit of the Lord shall rest on him,
> the spirit of wisdom and understanding,
> the spirit of counsel and might,
> the spirit of knowledge and the fear of the Lord. 3 His delight shall be in the fear of the Lord.

Beyond this there are many other OT refences, too numerous to mention, to revelations from the spiritual world, either God or angels, concerning the coming of the Christ.

On the other hand, the OP's presumption may be unwarranted that God was "showing to them that they were unable to live according to [his] standards by themselves." This idea does not show up until the teachings of St. Paul, who was no longer teaching Jewish doctrine. Jews actually do believe that they are able to live according to God's standards. Indeed, they believe that God punished them with the exile that Isaiah predicted in order to train them as the chosen nation, a "light unto the Gentiles," to whom the Messiah will be sent. (Isaiah 42:6) Christians, despite Jesus' admonition to "be perfect as your Heavenly Father is perfect," (Matthew 5:48) do not believe that living perfectly in accordance the law is possible.

**So yes, the spiritual world actively prepared the chosen people for the coming of the Messiah/Christ.  I know of no OT references to a battle in heaven which the OP asks about, but there were definitely angelic predictions about the coming of the Messiah, as well as direct communications from God through the prophets.**

Comment: You might've missed the difference between a process and predictions. All the verses you've cited are predictions of what will happen, rather than an active process of preparation of what will happen. It looks in Isiah more like they are just looking at the earth from the heaven and are waiting for a certain situation on the earth to transpire, after which they will launch the first coming of Messiah - all the process there is taking place on the earth, i.e. in the physical realm, rather than in the heavens, i.e. in the spiritual realm.